# not able to pass value to detailView from my masterView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a table in masterView, and a detailView, i have taken an id, set property and synthesized in detailView. In didSelectrowAtIndexPath method in masterView

```
detailViewObj.detailItem = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

the method in detailView

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem {
if (detailItem != newDetailItem) {
    [detailItem release];
    detailItem = [newDetailItem retain];
}}
```

is not getting called....any help???

Comment: are you not using properties...?

Answer (score 0):

Call it directly:

```
[detailViewObj setDetailItem: [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```